# SignalR validation on client side in react with .net core API

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, client-side-validation

Is there any security benefits or any other purpose to implement client side validation using SignalR.

In one of project I have seen that, using SignalR they are validating the react form by calling the api in .net core api.

Comment: Have a look at [How to validate SignalR request?](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34676).